# Gridview is not displaying text in Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have used a Gridview control in Windows 8.1 App.

**Below is the xaml Code**

```
                <GridView x:Name="gviewNavigation"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                  ItemClick="gvClick"
                                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                  ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True">
                            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Background="Red"
                                          Width="300">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="15"
                                                   Margin="20,12"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                   Text="{Binding text}"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   Foreground="{StaticResource BlackBrush}"
                                                   FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" />
                                        <Image Source="/Images/orange_underline@2x.png"
                                               Grid.Row="1"
                                               Visibility="{Binding is_alert,Converter={StaticResource stringVis}}"
                                               Height="2"
                                               Width="300"
                                               x:Name="imgOrg"
                                               Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        </GridView>
```

**Below is the C# code**

```
 gviewNavigation.ItemsSource = list;
```

I confirmed that binding works by having a converter for Text property of Textblock.

But the Bound text is not visible.

Same code works fine for Windows phone 8.1.

Please help!!

Comment: Did you check your output window? Try removing `FontFamily` or use the any default one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the **Grid Rowdefinition** to Auto for **GridView Itemtemplate** solved the issue.

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

The static resource **PhoneFontFamilyNormal** style is available only for phone project not for desktop projects

Comment: Removing PhoneFontFamilyNormal didn't work.
Still the text is not visible

Comment: I guess the issue is with "{Binding text}". Check if the binding property has a public get . If that doesn't help, post the c# code of the app.